# pdfmake: How to set the height for all rows?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, javascript-objects, pdfmake

I want to set the row height for all the rows in my table. I am currently specifying my styles like this:

```
table: {
    widths: ['33%', '34%', '33%'],
    heights: [40, 40],
    headerRows: 1,
```

That works very well if I have a known amount of rows, in this case, the first row and the table header get the height of 40. Everything underneath will fall back to the default height since I didn't specify anything different.

If I, however, have a table with a lot of rows or like in my case a table where the row count is dynamic, it is a tedious task to write each height into the object.

Is there any better way of applying styles to all rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the same height for all rows by assigning to "heights" a number instead of an array:

```
table: {
  widths: ['33%', '34%', '33%'],
  heights: 40, 
  headerRows: 1,
  body: [...]
}
```

Alternatively, you could dynamically generate an array of the right length in JavaScript. This is more cumbersome, but it would allow you to specify different heights for different rows in a programmatic way.

Look at the playground [here](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding in top and bottom. It is so handly, you can also set padding for specific row(s).

```
table: {
    widths: ['33%', '34%', '33%'],
    headerRows: 1,
    body: [...]
}, 
layout: {
    paddingTop: function (i, node) {
      return 5;
      //return (i === node.table.widths.length - 1) ? 5 : 5;
    },
    paddingBottom: function (i, node) {
      return 5;
      //return (i === node.table.widths.length - 1) ? 5 : 5;
    }
}
```